# Select a parent base on child id

Tags: html, css

I want to select the div containing a specific child.  More specifically i want to select the *div* which contains

```
<input type="checkbox" name="FRA10000" class="form-check-input " value="1" id="id_FRA10000" checked="">
```

in this piece of code:

```
<div class="form-check" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1669304504201_3527">
    <label id="yui_3_17_2_1_1669304504201_3526">
        <input type="hidden" name="FRA10000" value="0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="FRA10000" class="form-check-input " value="1" id="id_FRA10000" checked="">
        FRA1000-0 Révision 1re sec. Français, langue d’enseignement
    </label>
    <span class="text-nowrap">    
    </span>
</div>
```

I try `div:has( #id_FRA10000:not(:checked) )` but it doesn't work. Is it possible?

Comment: "it doesn't work" - what does that mean?

Comment: [:has()](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas) on firefox doesn't work

Comment: it works as expected on Chrome. Your checkbox is checked by default.

Comment: Since Firefox doesn't have support for `:has()` right now. This could only be done using JS.